# How Google makes ajax requests without invoking HttpRequest object

Tags: ajax, gmail

Firebug doesn't show any Ajax request being sent to Gmail when i delete any of my conversations. How they are doing it?

Comment: I believe this statement is wrong. The applicable **XmlHttpRequest object is used** if it (and JavaScript) are available. This *can be monitored/verified* in [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/). Make sure to enable the 'persist' setting. However, historically, google has also used iframes for "AJAX" such in the (at least historic) google map implementations. I have no idea what is current used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not use AJAX, they use iframes in most cases. For example I found they frenquently uses an iframe that points to this URL http://www.google.ch/blank.html and they uses to make the  requests and retrieve the response data.

A bit archaic, but most safe (maybe).